# Problems Including File

Tags: include

I read that if you create a php file and save it in the /wp-content/mu-plugins/ directory, WordPress will auto-load it.

However, I haven't yet figured it out. I don't have a folder named mu-plugins; it's just wp-content/plugins. I created a file at wp-content/plugins/echo-values.php, put a simple echo value in it and uploaded it, but I don't see the value I echoed in my source code.

I then opened wp-content/plugins/index.php and pasted in the following code:

```
require_once("echo-values.php");
require_once("/wp-content/plugins/echo-values.php");
```

Again, I don't see anything in my source code, so it looks like those files aren't being included. For good measure, I echoed some text in /wp-content/plugins/index.php, but I don't even see that in the source code.

Can anyone tell me the best way to include my own PHP file? It doesn't have to be in the plugins folder, though I was advised that's the best place to put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `/wp-content/mu-plugins` folder for

- single file
- autoloading

plugins. The only thing you will have to do is to use a plugin header comment in this file:

```
<?php /* Plugin Name: I am a MU-Plugin */
```

Then you will find a link on top of your `/wp-admin/plugins.php` page that says

> "Must-Use Plugins"

where you will find the list of mu-plugins. Those plugins can not be deactivated by an administrator or anyone else — only someone having access to your servers filesystem will be able to deactivate them by removing them from this folder.

Note, that plugins residing in subdirectories in this folder will *not* get loaded.

Comment: Oh, I see - I have to create the folder mu-plugins myself. I can then insert a file, which will autoload. I'll give it a try, thx.

Comment: Just a note: The code kaiser gave me works perfectly as is. I created a new file named counties.php, pasted in the code, then put the file in the mu-plugins folder and uploaded it.

Comment: note it will only autoload files in `mu-plugins` itself, not it's subfolders. you can use subfolders in mu-plugins but you would have to include those files from a loader file that is in the mu-plugins base directory itself.

Comment: @majick I already mentioned that in the answer :)

Comment: @kaiser yes i know, just an elaboration for how it can be done if wanted. :-)

Answer (score 3):

That is not how it works in WordPress. The `index.php` file is put in `plugins` directory to prevent unwanted behaviors, it isn't used for including files.

You should checkout [plugins development handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) to know the best way to include your files.